# Security of Jquery Ajax calls in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, security

I want to ask one little question about jquery ajax in asp.net 
and that is when we make a call with ajax it is open at client end and it work like a charm but the problem is website security do we have any particular technique to make ajax calls secure so that hacker cannot attack out site

Comment: should probably ask this question here instead: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You want to use HTTPS . Other than that, there are so many way to attack a site. Do you have any particular concern?

Answer (score 0):

Treat ajax calls to your server with the same level of care, variable validation/sanitation, and and general suspicion as you treat any other server-side page, controller, handler, etc.

Beyond that, you'll probably need to be more specific as to your security concerns to get meaningful suggestions.